# Reword close message to better reflect policy on sister sites

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons, user-experience

I would like to propose **changes to the close messages** for off-topic questions.

The close message when a question is put on hold as off-topic contains the following guidance for questions which were *not* selected for migration.

> - Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User.](//superuser.com/about)
> - Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault.](//serverfault.com/about)

**The problem** with this advice is that it fails to cover two extremely common misunderstandings.

- Low-quality content isn't welcome anywhere.
- If it's a FAQ on the suggested destination site, it will be closed as a duplicate before you can say "insulted and injured".

Especially for newcomers to the Stack Exchange family of sites, it is not too uncommon to experience being sent to another site with a kick in the rear, only to be kicked again when you arrive.  This does not foster a respectful and supportive atmosphere.  We have all been beginners here, and should shape our (automated) advice to help the newcomers get their problem resolved, not get kicked around.

Hence, I would like to add another sentence to these two messages.

> However, please consult their help section for guidance on formatting and content before posting there.

This is hopefully short enough to not burden the system with too much boilerplate, while better reflecting the actual procedure one should follow when a question is put on hold as off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: For the duplication case, is it possible that there could be a generated link that searches for similar terms? Maybe something like ending with "[Questions like this] may fit better on [SuperUser]" where "Questions like this" can link to a search that may produce the same question, but even if it doesn't will demonstrate what kind of questions do get asked.

Comment: An even better way IMHO, would be to indicate on which site it should go: "This questions about general computing hardware and software is off-topic for Stack Overflow (unless it directly involves tools used primarily for programming). You may find an [anwser to your question](https://superuser.com/search?TITLE_SEARCH) on Super User."

Comment: A pointer to existing answers on the nominated site would certainly be nice if it can be done precisely and reliably, but is more of a development task and so not really in scope for this simple enhancement suggestion.